# ios UICollectionView - setting auto height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollection view to create 3x4 matrix of buttons. Its good looking in iPhone4 with has small height. Also collection view is not scrolling, as it shows 3x4 matrix buttons in available space.

Now when I run the same app on iPHone5, i see lots of space at the bottom below the matrix of buttons. I would like collection view to increase the vertical spacing between the cells.
Can some one guide me please?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a collection view for this? Can you just lay them out by hand?

Comment: @frozendevil, the list might increase in next versions of app. So, I opted for collection view which handles the memory and scrolling effectively.

Comment: Then aăâ's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make UICollectionViewFlowLayout by math, for example:

```
CGRect mainRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat mainWidth = mainRect.size.width;
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = mainWidth/10;
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(mainWidth/4, mainWidth/4);
```

Then just assign because UICollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewLayout

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get it done by some property of collection view?

Comment: Assign flowLayout to collectionViewLayout property. See my edit.