# Swift can't get UICollectionView to layout properly

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to get UICollectionView to automatically layout cells with auto adjusting cell sizes. My layout needs to have 3 cells wide by 4 cells high, it looks good on a iPhone 5 by when I sample it on a iPhone 6 the cells are stacked at the top of the UICollectionView. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

tl;dr Left screen is good(iPhone 5), I need the right to look the same (iPhone 6). How to make cells auto adjust size?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [ios UICollectionView - setting auto height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721559/ios-uicollectionview-setting-auto-height) that explains how to auto size cells. I then applied Swift syntax to make it work for Swift.